# Magento MySQL connection close necessary

Tags: php, magento

I have opened MySQL database connection using the code below

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

Do I need to close this mysql connection on my own or the Magento handles it by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to close it.

Comment: Thanks, A little doubt yet. If I have that line of code twice in my script. Will those be considered as two separate connection or still one. please...

Comment: The function name is `getSingleton()`, which answers your question: it is the same connection, whenever you access that model…

Comment: For Magento 2 It is necessary to close connection?? $connection->close();

Answer (score 0):

you need to close db connection because if you not close connection with db in custom query then it will become sleeping query.
that the problem i am facing right mysql server is full of sleeping queries.
i finding solution for that one.

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); ` gets an already open connection. If you close it, other code will fail to reuse that connection.